# boto EC2 region is wrong even though its set in environment and in .boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, ansible

I'm trying to run the EC2 Ansible hosts scripts (/etc/ansible/hosts), and this was working previously.  This problem doesn't seem to be related to ansible, it appears to be just a boto issue.

We've distilled the problem down to boto not respecting the ec2_region that is set.  Here is the error, where boto reveals it is attempting to use us-east-1 (the boto default):

```
/etc/ansible/hosts
    send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 217\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nHost: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r\nUser-Agent: Boto/2.34.0 Python/2.6.9 Linux/3.14.20-20.44.amzn1.x86_64\r\n\r\n'
    send: '***&Action=DescribeInstances&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2014-12-08T18%3A56%3A08Z&Version=2014-05-01&Signature=***%3D'
    reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'
    header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    header: Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 18:56:08 GMT
    header: Server: AmazonEC2
    Looks like AWS is down again:
    EC2ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response><Errors><Error><Code>UnauthorizedOperation</Code><Message>You are not authorized to perform this operation.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>e0a4a474-e422-47ea-b9c7-3231d1a328dd</RequestID></Response>
```

The region variable appears to be properly set:

```
declare -x EC2_REGION="us-west-1"
```

And the .boto region is also set:

```
ec2_region_name = us-west-1
ec2_region_endpoint = ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I have also attempted it while commenting out the setting in .boto an in bashrc (where env is set).

Running the `ec2-describe-instances` command from the commandline works fine.

Comment: Check if you have /etc/boto.cfg file

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: @helloV - Thanks for asking.  I limited the regions in `/etc/ansible/ec2.ini`, which works, but isn't exactly what we want (ec2.ini will limit the regions acted upon, but we want to specify exactly which regions to address in a given task).  Eventually, will probably have to return to this issue and figure it out.  Any thoughts?  BTW, I had checked boto.cfg (its not there)

Comment: @helloV - Found it - see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

I had to tweak the following knobs (in `/etc/ansible/ec2.ini`):

```
# This is the normal destination variable to use. If you are running Ansible
# from outside EC2, then 'public_dns_name' makes the most sense. If you are
# running Ansible from within EC2, then perhaps you want to use the internal
# address, and should set this to 'private_dns_name'. The key of an EC2 tag
# may optionally be used; however the boto instance variables hold precedence
# in the event of a collision.
destination_variable = private_dns_name

# For server inside a VPC, using DNS names may not make sense. When an instance
# has 'subnet_id' set, this variable is used. If the subnet is public, setting
# this to 'ip_address' will return the public IP address. For instances in a
# private subnet, this should be set to 'private_ip_address', and Ansible must
# be run from within EC2. The key of an EC2 tag may optionally be used; however
# the boto instance variables hold precedence in the event of a collision.
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address
```

This let's ansible have visibility to the instances w/o public ips.